# Replace Strings in HTML with anchors without breaking existing anchors

Tags: html, .net, regex, vb.net, outlook-addin

I am trying to replace strings in a HTML string with anchors in every e-mail I open in outlook, without breaking existing anchors. The strings have a format of X123456, where X can be F,P,R,G,K,IT and 123456 is some number. The anchors have a format like 'X123456'. After lot of tweaking I ended with this code:

```
Dim content As String = mail.HTMLBody
content = RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, "(?<!<[^>]*)(?<!t_)(?<!__"">)(?<![.])(?<![0-9a-zA-Z_-])[fFpPiImMrRkKgG][tT]?\d{5,7}(?!-)(?!\&)(?![a-zA-Z0-9])", AddressOf MakeLink, RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

MakeLink recieves matches and makes the anchors. This works great with small e-mails, but is unusable if the email gets bigger.

I thing I overcomplicated the regex. I am also open for a different approach like using XML document, I am simply not too deep in web solutions.

Thank you for all ideas in advance.

Comment: The use of star or plus within lookbehind (`(?<!<[^>]*)`) is terribly devastating.

Comment: Consider using an HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Yes, without It, the performance is great, but It starts to replace strings inside other elements, so I end up with broken HTML.